# my carousel in nextjs13 usually shows an error after going two to three times round the array of object data i provided for it basic control actionss

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, next.js13

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./styles.module.css";
import React from 'react'
import type { RootState } from '../../app/store'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { increment1 } from './adCarouselSlice'


interface CarouselProps {
    Services: {
        category:string;
        src:string;
        services: {
        id: number;
        name: string; 
        src: string; 
        link: string;
        }[]
    }[]; // An array of services to display in the carousel,
}


const AdCarousel: React.FC<CarouselProps>   = ({Services}) => {
  
    const activeIndex = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.carousel.value)
    

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const dispatch1 = useDispatch()

    
    useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch(increment1());
    }, 20500);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  },[]);

    const [inneractiveIndex, setinnerActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  
    const handleNextinner = () => {
        setinnerActiveIndex((prevIndex) =>
            prevIndex === Services[activeIndex].services.length - 1 ? prevIndex = 0 : prevIndex += 1
        );
    };

    const handlePrevinner = () => {
        setinnerActiveIndex((prevIndex) =>
        prevIndex === Services[activeIndex].services.length - 1 ? prevIndex = 0 : prevIndex += 1
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            try{
                handleNextinner();
            }catch(error){
        
            }
            
        }, 1450);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [Services[activeIndex].services[inneractiveIndex]]);


    return (
        <div className={styles.parent}>
            <div className={styles.titleCard}>
                <span>Instantly Link Up Directly to a viriety of</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.mainCard}>
                <div className={styles.cardL} >
                    <div>
                      <span className={styles.titleSpan}>{Services[activeIndex].category}</span>
                    </div>
                  <img className={styles.img} src={Services[activeIndex].src}/>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.cardS} >
                    <div>
                        <span className={styles.titleSpan}>{Services[activeIndex].services[inneractiveIndex].name} Service Providers</span>
                    </div>
                    <img className={styles.img} src={Services[activeIndex].services[inneractiveIndex].src}/>
                </div>
            
      </div>
        </div>

    );
};

export default AdCarousel;`
```

```
"use client"
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Services } from './adCarouselData'

export interface AdCarouselState {
  value: number
}

const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);

const initialState: AdCarouselState = {
  value: 0,
}

export const adCarouselSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'carousel',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment1: (state) => {
       
      state.value === Services.length - 1 ?state.value = 0 :state.value += 1;
      }
    },
})


// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { increment1} = adCarouselSlice.actions

export default adCarouselSlice.reducer
```

i used the reduxtoolkit to manage the state of the parent array of object,
and i use the usestate to manage the nested array of object as it relate to the parent array of object,
while i used the useeffect to automate it,
but after three iterations of the parent array of object and it related children it then throw an error